# Function for adding the arguments doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm having doubts about the following code.

When I use the function with arguments such as these `sum_warehouses_stock("CALL", "2", "B", "10", "CALL", 1 )`, it returns zero instead of adding the numbers.  Have I overlooked something?

```
function sum_warehouses_stock(){

    $total = 0;
    $warehouses = func_get_args();

    foreach($warehouses as $warehouse){
    $warehouse = str_replace(["+","<",">","B"], "", $warehouse);
        if (is_numeric($warehouse)){
             $total += $warehouse;
        }
     }
     return $total;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, I get 13 with your sample input.

Comment: Works for me too: https://3v4l.org/omkfo

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback guys, I'll look into it - it could be an environmental variable.

Comment: Var dump warehouses lets see if it is returning false or array of your args. `var_dump($warehouses);`

Comment: works for me too.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `func_get_args()` is old fashioned, we have variadic functions since PHP 5.6: `function sum_warehouses_stock(...$warehouses){` automatically populates `$warehouses` with an array of arguments.

Comment: @miken32 interesting.  Could you kindly give a full example for a dummy to follow?

Comment: That's the full example. Make that your function signature, and get rid of the line with `func_get_args()`. Done. Details here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics

Comment: So the `func_get_args()` line is redundant?  Function will work exactly the same without it in PHP5.6+?

Comment: As long as you update your function signature, yes.